# I could use some help finding the scripting tab

Tags: python, animation, sculpting

Hello I am just starting out with blender. I am taking the animation class on bloop one of the lessons calls for using the scripting tab to find rigify I think its called. My problem is I can't find the scripting tab. I am using blender 2.8.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: If it turns out that you do indeed need to scroll, as ZargulTheWizard suggests, that will be achieved by middle mouse clicking anywhere in the tab area, and then dragging left or right. I'm pointing this out because many don't know about this drag function, and it wouldn't be obvious at first glance that the middle mouse button is the key to getting it done.

Comment: Tank you for the advice as well the wizard got it right.

Answer (score 0):

All the “tabs” are at the top of the window in the default layout. The scripting tab is farthest to the right-hand side, so you may need to scroll if your monitor is small.

For more information on Blender’s UI, check out [Blender’s Documentation](http://docs.blender.org)

Comment: It was just a little scroll to the right that was helpful.